# can i cast metadata class type object to partial class type object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, downcast

i have something like this

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MetaData_Course_application))]
partial class COURSE_APPLICATION
{

}
public class MetaData_Course_application
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string ENTRANCE_ROLL_NO { get; set; }
    public int SESSION_ID { get; set; }
    public int ENTRANCE_ID { get; set; }
    public Int64 COURSE_ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DATE_OF_APPLICATION { get; set; }
    public Int64 RANK { get; set; }
    public Int64 STUDENT_ID { get; set; }
    public bool FEE_PAID { get; set; }
    public bool IS_CANCLED_BY_STUDENT { get; set; }
}
    and now i want

    public void ApplyForCourse(ERP.MetaData_Course_application Coll)
    {
    COURSE_APPLICATION Collection=(COURSE_APPLICATION)coll;
    context = new ERPDataContext();
    context.COURSE_APPLICATIONs.InsertOnSubmit(Collection);
    context.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

something like this is it possible? if not what should be the best possible solution? please help thank in advance

Comment: What is "Collection"?

Comment: object of COURSE_APPLICATION class(table)

Comment: What does not work? What is the real Problem?

Comment: COURSE_APPLICATION Collection=(COURSE_APPLICATION)coll;